# Multi-field sort using xsl:sort

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I am writing a transform and to make it easier diff the result, I need to sort the output on multiple fields.  I can't find any documentation discussing how to do this and it is important that I get it right.

Is this the right way to do this?

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="MemoryBank | ParameterSet | Template">
    <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
    <xsl:sort select="attribute::Id"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Sample XML would look similar to this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FirmwareConfiguration>
    <MemoryBank Id="EEPROM" Address="0" Size="262144" BitsPerWord="8">
      <Description>2 Mbit EEPROM</Description>
    </MemoryBank>
    <MemoryBank Id="PRAM" Address="12288" Size="53248" BitsPerWord="32">
      <Description>Program Memory</Description>
    </MemoryBank>
    <ParameterSet Id="GainReduction" Size="16" BitsPerWord="24">
      <Description>Gain Reduction Values</Description>
    </ParameterSet>
    <ParameterSet Id="AlgorithmState" Size="35" BitsPerWord="24">
      <Description>Firmware Variable Space</Description>
    </ParameterSet>
    <Template Id="05b4bcb0-2d04-4742-9fdd-bd60496502a9">
      <FormatSpecifier>
        <SignBits>0</SignBits>
        <IntegerBits>5</IntegerBits>
        <FractionalBits>0</FractionalBits>
      </FormatSpecifier>
    </Template>
    <Template Id="0667ae14-3b5a-4b38-8c35-d575add6df65">
      <FormatSpecifier>
        <SignBits>0</SignBits>
        <IntegerBits>1</IntegerBits>
        <FractionalBits>0</FractionalBits>
      </FormatSpecifier>
    </Template>
</FirmwareConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the right way to do this?

Yes.

The [XSLT 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#sorting) simply states that "The first xsl:sort child specifies the primary sort key, the second xsl:sort child specifies the secondary sort key and so on" without spelling out in detail what "primary sort key" and "secondary sort key" mean.

The XSLT 2.0 spec [spells out the whole process in detail](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#sorting-process) and makes it clear that the sort is based first on the first `<xsl:sort>`, and the second is checked only for items with the same value for the first, etc.